# Upgrading AsteriskNOW to Asterisk 12

Tags: asterisk

Can anyone give directions on the best way to upgrade AsteriskNOW to use Asterisk 12? I'm currently running AsteriskNOW 3 which uses Asterisk 11.5.

I've spent a couple of hours searching but can't find anyone documenting the process (i.e. on forums or blogs), and can't really afford to 'suck it and see'. I'm hoping it's as simple as doing a yum update, but something tells me it's not going to be that easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can upgrade Asterisk manually. Notes on upgrade to Asterisk 12 can be found on the Asterisk wiki [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Upgrading+to+Asterisk+12), and notes on [installing and configuring](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+Installation+and+Configuration) Asterisk 12 - in particular, [pjproject](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Installing+pjproject) - are also on the wiki. There are also packages for Asterisk 12 available from the asterisk-12 repository on [packages.asterisk.org](http://packages.asterisk.org/centos/centos-asterisk-12.repo), if you want to go that route. However, you would also need to [upgrade FreePBX to FreePBX 12](http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FD/Updating+FreePBX+Official+Distro).
2. Your other option would be to go and just download the FreePBX 12 Alpha from FreePBX. This may be the easiest route, but it would require moving and/or re-creating your configuration.

A bigger question however is: why do you want to upgrade to Asterisk 12?

Don't get me wrong, we're very proud of it. The core has been substantially overhauled, which has yielded a new SIP channel driver and stack; a powerful new interface in ARI; and some really cool capabilities in the bridging core. The flexibility of the new engine affords a lot of power for folks who are building systems on top of Asterisk. However, it is not a [Long Term Support](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions) release - and as such, unless you feel comfortable looking through the changes in Asterisk 12 and working through the configuration differences and the new features, you may be well served by waiting for the FreePBX system to provide a more suitable upgrade path.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. As you hinted at, the only reason we need to upgrade is to take advantage of the updates to AMI/ARI, specifically the improved way it handles call/transfer events (see [other SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459508/reliably-identifying-and-tracking-asterisk-calls-using-c-sharp-and-aster-net)). I guess then it's a question of waiting :( Do you know of any anticipated release dates? Thanks again for your response, much appreciated.

Comment: Asterisk 12 install on option 1) will result not working system.All other comments seams ok.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean "will not result working system". Asterisk 12 works just fine on CentOS 6, which is the basis of AsteriskNOW. FreePBX 12 supports Asterisk 12 as well - but since AsteriskNOW uses FreePBX 2.11, you have to upgrade it as well.

Comment: @iam: If you'd like a FreePBX based system, I would use the FreePBX 12 distro. We don't have a release date yet for AsteriskNOW to support Asterisk 12 - we're working hard to maintain Asterisk 12 itself, while the FreePBX guys have been awesome at building out the UI to support Asterisk 12, and hence were able to put a distro together in record time (seriously: it was very impressive). You could also install Asterisk 12 by itself on a stand-alone system using packages if you want to just play around with it.

Comment: @MattJordan - thanks for the further info. With the Asterisk 12 version of the FreePBX distro still being in Alpha, I'd be hesitant to put it in a production environment - not sure if that's warranted? I'm guessing there's not much lost in moving from AsteriskNOW to FreePBX distro either, it looks like they're both comparable in terms of what they come shipped with? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any description of such process becuase it just will not work.

Asterisk Now web will not work with asterisk 12.

But if you REALY think you have enought free time to fix all bugs/issues after version change, you can compile asterisk from source.